# Algorithm to find possible variables in multiple connected equations

Tags: algorithms, logic

I am new here. I am trying to come up with an algorithm that can give me the unknown values in the following equation.

```
find lowest possible x, y and z whole number variables where:

2x = y+z &&
6y = x+z &&
3z = x+y
```

I am trying to come up with a formula that tells me:
What are the possible values of the variable x y z. The values must be positive whole numbers greater than zero and should be the lowest possible whole numbers. If the equation is impossible the formula should tell me the same.

I have tried coming up with a couple of formulas but my efforts have bore no fruit.

PS: I am not so conversant with the tags on this site if I have left any out please add.

Comment: This looks like a pure math question about solving a system of 3 linear equations in 3 unknowns.  What is the connection to computer science?

Comment: You problem could be solved using an integer linear program, and minimizing $x+y+z$ - However, your system of equations have one unique solution, namely $x = y = z = 0$, so with the added restrictions that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are positive numbers the system is infeasible.